# Getting a Stream of objects based on value of other member object

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a Java class of type `Project` which contains Map of type `Process` and class Process subsequently contains Map of type `Activity`.

```
public class Project {
    private String name;
    private Path path;
    private Map<String, Process> processes;
    //getters and setters
    }

public class Process {
    private String name;
    private String path;
    private Map<String, Activity> activities;
    //getters and setters
    }

public class Activity {
    private String name;
    private String type;
    //getters and setters
    }
```

I'm trying to write a function which will return a `Stream` of `Process` or `Process.path` where the `Process` contains at least one activity having `type="starter"` i.e. `Activity.type="starter"`.

I came up with the below code but it returns a `Stream<Activity>` whereas what I'm looking for is a `Stream<Process>` or `Stream<String>` containing the `path`.

```
project.processes.values().stream()
    .flatMap(process -> process.getActivities().values().stream()
            .filter(activity -> "starter".equals(activity.getType())));
```

What is the most efficient way of doing this?

Comment: you're doing it right, what else are you looking for?

Comment: @Naman I want to return Stream<Process> containing those activities not Stream<Activity>

Comment: In which case you'd need to filter instead of mapping the objects as,         `Stream<Process> processStream = project.processes.values()
                .stream()
                .filter(process -> process.getActivities()
                        .values()
                        .stream()
                        .anyMatch(activity -> "starter".equals(activity.getType())));
        Stream<String> processPathStream = ....
                .map(Process::getPath);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `flatMap` if you want a `Stream<Process>` because `flatMap` will "destroy" information about the processes.

You should create a "nested" stream:

```
project.getProcesses().values().stream()
        .filter(x -> 
                x.getActivities().values().stream().anyMatch(
                        y -> "starter".equals(y.getType())
                )
        );
```

Now it's a `Stream<Process>`.

Answer (score 1):

The code given will map the processes to activities via the `.flatMap` operator.

The operator You are looking for is probably `.filter` if I understand correcly the request of

> I'm trying to write a function which will return a Stream of Process or Process.path where the Process contains at least one activity having type="starter" i.e. Activity.type="starter".

```
project.processes.values().stream()
    .filter(process -> process.getActivities().values().stream()
            .filter(activity -> "starter".equals(activity.getType())).findFirst().isPresent());
```

You can then map to `Project.path` via a `.map` operator. Given the previous operation as `processStream`, we might write

```
processStream.map(process -> process.getPath())
```

It may be worth to note that, if the list of activities may be finite, the `.findFirst` terminal operation may be substituted for a `.count` terminal operation. It all depends on the clarity of the code, and the speed requirements of the code.